# How to parse string after nth delimiter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, charindex

I want to parse a string after the `nth` underscore. For example in the string:

> 2020_Campaign_SG_Test Email

I need to:

- Extract the text `Campaign` after the 1st underscore and before the
  2nd, and create column called Type
- Extract the text `SG` after the the 2nd underscore and before the
  3rd, and create column called Segment
- Extract the text `Test Email` after the 3rd underscore, and create
  column called Name

Comment: Which db engine are you using? If you're using SQL Server 2016 or greater, you might be able to utilize [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 17

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio is not a dbms system.  What is your SQL Server version???

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL Server 16 or greater, you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (ensure your compatibility level is at least 130 to use it).

I was unable to get the following code working on any fiddle links, but you can copy/paste it into https://sqliteonline.com/ (set it to MS SQL, connect, copy/paste the code and run):

[image]

## Code

Here's the simplest form I was able to come up with:

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT
      value v,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) n
    from STRING_SPLIT('2020_Campaign_SG_Test Email','_')  
)

SELECT
    [2] [Type],
    [3] Segment,
    [4] [Name]
  FROM x
  PIVOT(
    MAX(v) FOR n IN([2],[3],[4])
  ) y
```

---

## Output

This generates the following (first line is table header):

```
# Type        Segment    Name
  Campaign    SG         Test Email
```

---

## Explanation

#### `STRING_SPLIT` section

```
WITH x AS (
  SELECT
      value v,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) n
    from STRING_SPLIT('2020_Campaign_SG_Test Email','_')  
)
```

In the first part, I create a temporary named result set `x` (aka [CTE or common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)). The result set uses the `STRING_SPLIT` function to split your string `2020_Campaign_SG_Test Email` on the underscore `_` character. I also number the output of the result set using [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

This generates the following (first line is table header):

```
# v              n
  2020           1
  Campaign       2
  SG             3
  Test Email     4
```

#### `PIVOT` section

```
SELECT
    [2] [Type],
    [3] Segment,
    [4] [Name]
  FROM x
  PIVOT(
    MAX(v) FOR n IN([2],[3],[4])
  ) y
```

The second part then takes our result set `x` and transposes rows of data to columns with respect to aggregations using the [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15) operator. The aggregate function here is `MAX(v) FOR n IN([2],[3],[4])`. Using the `MAX` function removes all the `NULL` values (otherwise it would pivot and each `v` to its own column and add `NULL` values for the other columns) and only gets us the second, third, and fourth items as output (since you only specified those 3 items as output in your original question).

Comment: @CMB - **WARNING**: [`STRING_SPLIT` explicitly documents that the returned rows "might be in any order"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) (likely intended to be used on "row" data), and is thus _not safe_ to be used this way.  Practically, this may work most of the time.  You have been warned!

Comment: Going off of what @Clockwork-Muse mentioned, you *might* be able to use something like `CHARINDEX` (as [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207293/182956) shows) to force an order, but beware that if two identical values appear in the string (after the split), you can get incorrect results. See [this other answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/207275/182956) for more details too.